# magento api connect error

Tags: api, magento, while-loop

Getting all customer list and create a new customer using soap api...

```
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://j-shop.z/shop/api/soap/?wsdl');
//  $proxy = new SoapClient(null, array('uri' => http://j-shop.z/shop/api/soap/?wsdl"));                
            $sessionId = $proxy->login('testuser', 'test123');
            var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer.list', array('filters', '*')));
            $newCustomer = array(
                'firstname'  => 'First',
                'lastname'   => 'Last',
                'email'      => 'test@example.com',
                'password_hash'   => md5('password'),
                'store_id'   => 0,
                'website_id' => 0
            );

        $newCustomerId = $proxy->call($sessionId,'customer.create',array($newCustomer));
```

Comment: i already double checked the apiuser and api key which i created in magento but i am still getting this error of SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Access denied. [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /home/inder/etc/php_apps/www/j-shop.z/public_html/izapapi/app/controllers/retailerController.php [line:protected] => 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also try it

i think problem in api.xml

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/

Answer (score 1):

Open php_soap in your wamp or xammp,
I think its not open,
So firstly you check your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

please set fault in api.xml so easily fix it